# With MonoTouch (monodevelop) how to debug IPad?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I can't find any options (tried all options under project/solution options) to debug my IPad.  All the configs show IPhone only. I've seem some comments that it appears to be version related?  I just do check update and I appear to be on the latest. 3.0.3.5

Answer (score 6):

Just go to menu `project` -> `iPhone simulator Target` -> choose `iPad simulator`.
Or go to menu `Run` -> `Run With` -> `iPad simulator`. 
Hope this help!

**Update**:
Another option maybe help for your case
Go to `project option`(double click in project name) -> `iPhone build` -> try choose another sdk version (Which version can you see?).
Then go to `iPhone Application` -> `Summary tab` -> choose Device iPad () and `Deployment target` is 3.2 (3.2 is the version of iPad's SDK, if you can't see it, I think you should update your Xcode and sdk).

Comment: Under simulator target, all I have is "default", no other options.  Doing Run->Run with ->IPad simulator does not debug, it just runs it.  My question is about debugging which I still can not do.

Comment: Could you debug iPad application in your Xcode? Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, ChrisNTR from Xamarin said:

> The reason you're not seeing those options is because you have the MWC.Core.MT (class library) selected and not the actual MonoTouch project (MWC.iOS) as per Rolf's screenshot.

:)